# How to monitor gRPC Server?

Tags: memory, monitoring, grpc

Does gRPC server span a separate thread for each incoming request?

I think, prometheus helps monitor incoming & outgoing traffic.  But, how to monitor gRPC Server like Threads (Idle/ Active), Memory Usage (heap), IO, sessions etc?

Finally, any documentation on gRPC Server internals will help.

Comment: Which language? gRPC tries to be idiomatic in each language, so different languages behave differently.

Comment: Interested in Java.

Answer (score 0):

By default server utilize cached thread pool, but we can provide another one while building the server instance.

```
ServerBuilder<?> builder = ServerBuilder.forPort(port)
    .executor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))
    // ...
;
```

From the javadoc "executor" method:

> /**    * Provides a custom executor.
>
> It's an optional
>   parameter. If the user has not provided an executor when the server is
>   built, the builder will use a static cached thread pool.
>
> The server won't take ownership of the given executor. It's
>   caller's responsibility to shut down the executor when it's
>   desired.
>   
> @return this
>   
> @since 1.0.0
>   
> public abstract T executor(@Nullable Executor executor);

You can provide some name for your pool & try to monitor activity with VisualVM